# Can I redefine \chapter? Where do I find the defaults of the standard commands?

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I need two different types of first-chapter-pages in one document. One type (Typ I) is for "normal" chapters appearing as chapters. The other type (Typ II) is for the Appendix ("Anhang"), the list of tables and some others. The thing is first, I have a group of Typ II chapters, then a group of Typ I's and again a group pof Typ II's. For making the problem not that hard, I'd like to know where I can find the default settings for the `\chapter` command.
I have solved it with a general redefining of `\chapter`, but the list of tables a.s.o. also changes its heading, which isn't supposed to be.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{inputenc}\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}\usepackage{fancyhdr}\usepackage{layout}\usepackage[top=25mm,bottom=25mm,left=3cm,right=3cm,headheight=15pt]{geometry}\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{titlesec}\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\bfseries\Large}{\thechapter.\quad}{0pt}{}\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-4cm}{40pt}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{rotating}\usepackage[graphicx]{realboxes}\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsmath}\usepackage{amssymb}\usepackage{calc}\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}\usepackage{section}\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none,backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}
\usepackage{caption}\usepackage{section}\usepackage{csquotes}\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
%\makeatletter
    %\def\@makeschapterhead#1{\vspace*{-50\p@}{\parindent 
    %\z@ 
    %\raggedright    \normalfont    \interlinepenalty\@M    \Huge \bfseries    \thechapter.\quad    #1\par\nobreak    \vskip 20\p@}}
%\makeatother
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\bfseries\Large}{\thechapter.\quad}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{40pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\include{Titelseite}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\tableofcontents                    %Typ II
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark \rightmark}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\include{Zusatz}                    %Typ II
\pagestyle{fancy}
\restoregeometry
\include{Einleitung}            %Typ I
\include{Theorie}                   %Typ I
\include{Motivation}            %Typ I
\include{Diskussion}            %Typ I
\include{Zusammenfassung}    %Typ I
\include{Durchfuhrung}      %Typ I
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\newgeometry{top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm}
\setcounter{page}{6}
\singlespacing
\include{Anhang}                    %Typ II
\pagestyle{fancy}
\include{Eidesstatt}            %Typ II
\end{document}
```

I also would like to have figures and tables another numbering for Typ II.

(I'll also need these settings when I create TYP I manually. (For the list of tables is Typ II and I don't think I can redefine the heading of the list of tables, can I?)

Comment: Of course you can redefine `\chapter`. It's in the file `report.cls`. Apparently, you have screwed up the definition for `\chapter*` as well, which is used by `\tableofcontents` and the other `\listof....` macros.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but your preamble has duplicate entries for the `section`, `caption`, and `csquotes` packages. `titlesec` and `layout` may be redundant. `graphics` has been deprecated in favor of `graphicx`, and should be removed.

Comment: I think looking into [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html) would have been a good idea. It would have presented classes that make it *very* easy to change the appearance of chapter titles, no matter if usual or for chapter in the appendix. Right now, you are redefining the code base that is for experenced users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the definition of `\chapter` from `report.cls`

```
\newcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\def\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn
                   \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
                 \else
                   \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
                   \@afterheading
                 \fi}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
```

A crucial command is

```
\def\secdef#1#2{\@ifstar{#2}{\@dblarg{#1}}}
```

See also the file [classes.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/classes.pdf) which explains the chapter settings as well. (Best read `source2e` as well)